# Unable to install latest stable Release of Redis on CentOS 7

Tags: redis, centos7

I followed below steps to install Redis on CentOS. But Redis `3.2.x` version got downloaded, I want more recent version (i.e `4.0.11` or `5.0.x`) to be downloaded.

I need steps how to upgrade the Redis current installation? I used below steps while installation

We can use yum to install EPEL:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

As soon as we finish installing EPEL, we can use yum once again to install Redis:

```
sudo yum install redis
```

After a few minutes  this installation will be completed and then you can start the Redis service:

```
sudo systemctl start redis.service
```

There is always the chance for Redis to start on boot, all you have to do is enable it through the enable command:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis
```

If you want to check Redis`s status you should run the following:

```
sudo systemctl status redis.service
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell  - How to update the redis from X to Y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Remi repository keeps up with the latest binaries.  While you can add them to your repos (see https://rpms.remirepo.net), you can just point yum directly at the rpm file there as well (e.g. yum install -y http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/remi/x86_64/redis-5.0.0-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm).

Edit: Regarding an upgrade, I assumed you don't have any data at this point, so I would suggest a quick `yum uninstall redis` before installing the latest.  If you really need to upgrade with data and all, you need to just be sure to preserve your persistent data files and replace them before starting the new version.